# how can I assign the values to an httpheaders header in angular

Tags: angular, http, get

I explain. I am making a request to a post request with some parameters to an api, it returns a token which I must include in the get requests that I do later. So far so good. the problem is when I'm going to make the request get, in the headers of that request I must include the access_token and the type_token that I get in the POST request for that I declared an httpOptions object of type HttpHeaders as specified in the Angular documentation but I can not to make it work. what am I doing wrong? Here I leave the code of what I have done so far:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {


  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': '',
      'Authorization': ''

    })
  }

    parametros = {
      'grant_type':'client_credentials',
      'client_id': 1,
      'client_secret': 'clientSecret'
    }


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  obtenerToken(){
    return this.http.post<any>('URL/oauth/token',this.parametros).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.httpOptions.set('Accept','result.token_type');
        this.httpOptions.set('Authorization','result.access_token');
      },error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  obtenerInmuebles(){
    return this.http.get('URL',this.httpOptions);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the quotes from the result:

```
    this.httpOptions.set('Accept',result.token_type);
    this.httpOptions.set('Authorization',result.access_token);
```